# print specific content page after every page in crystal report and exclude it from page number count

Tags: crystal-reports

How do I print a specific content page after every page in Crystal Reports? I want to repeat content in separate page **after each page**, and I want to exclude these pages from the page number count.

For example: Print invoice details page, and after page print page contains "Guarantee Rules" and "Customer Rights".

Comment: i tried to use page footer section 
but problem is appear only one time after all pages and count in page number count

Comment: what is the current hierarchy of your report now? There are some missing info in ur question

Comment: i created report with multi sections and can modify it if find suitablesolution for my problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

For `customer rights` section section expert select option `New Page After` and the section after this section take a sub report and in that chose the fields and layout that prints the required invoice, Which will print invoice in new page after customer rights